# Unable to create Dataset in Power bi Using Power bi apis

Tags: api, powerbi

I'm trying to add a dataset to the power bi by taking the data from database in Postman. But I'm getting the FailedToDeserializeDatasetError. I'm not getting why this error is happening. I gave the database name and server name correctly. Please help me to solve this.

[This error I'm getting in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC2gi.png)

Comment: "Failed to deserialize" can be due to an internet proxy being in use. Is this from a corporate network or home network? If from a corporate network, check if you have an internet proxy and enter proxy config into Postman

Comment: Now it is creating dataset name in power bi workspace. but when we click on that dataset, it is showing the error that, the data source cannot be accessed by a gateway: Server:.........; Database:........

Comment: Did you make a change to get it to create the dataset? If so please post an answer rather than just asking another question.

Comment: It is the home network. Still, I'm getting that error "Failed to deserialize" but I tried by providing different raw data to API in the postman, that is creating the dataset in power bi, but when I try to open that dataset, it is showing the error that the data source cannot be accessed by a gateway: Server:.........; Database:.......

Comment: Well that gateway error is a normal error if you create a dataset that requires a gateway but you don't have one installed or it can't access the dataset. I don't know if you've done any of these things from your problem description.

Comment: did this issue got resolved?